# Is it true that if a graph is $3$-connected, then it is $3$-edge-connected?

Tags: graph-theory

In order for a graph to be $3$-connected, it is not disconnected after one of its vertices of degree $3$ is removed.  I tried to find the contradiction of that statement by counterexample, but I exhausted my attempts for more than an hour.

Any suggestions or thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\kappa$ be the minimal number $k$ for which a graph $G$ is $k$-(vertex)-connected and let $\kappa'$ be the minimal number $k$ for which the graph is $k$-edge-connected.

Then one has $\kappa \leq \kappa'$; here this means that if a graph $G$ is $3$-vertex-connected ($\kappa \geq 3$) then it also is $3$-edge-connected ($\kappa'\geq 3$). This can be shown by repeatedly applying the following lemma:

$\textbf{Lemma}$: if one removes an edge from a $k$-vertex-connected graph, the resulting graph is $k-1$-vertex connected.

It follows that a $k$-vertex-connected graph cannot have a $(k-1)$-edge cut, i.e. if $\kappa(G) = k$ then $\kappa'(G) \geq k$.

Comment: Figured out already.  Anyway, thanks for the good answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Note that your definition of a 3-connected graph does not seem to be standard, it would usually be a graph where removing up to 3 vertices does not make it disconnected.**

Now to your questions: Take a cycle. Removing any vertex never makes it disconnected, but by removing two edges will.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I understand what you are saying about the note you posted